# The Walking Dead "Alone" timeline

Tags: the-walking-dead

At the beginning of the episode *Alone* ([S04E13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alone_%28The_Walking_Dead%29)) Daryll and Glenn pull up on someone new named Bob (Stookey) but Daryll is really with Maggie's sister and Glenn is alone. This makes no sense.

Comment: This question is terrible. What exactly are you trying to ask? I've voted to close, please edit your question into something approaching comprehensibility.

Comment: Please try to clarify what your asking, it is not a very good question. I'm flagging this question as low quality.

Comment: The beginning was the past. The story is told a *little* bit out of order. Please don't watch Memento as it may cause you to explode.

Comment: On [movies.se]: [What was with that scene with Glenn and Daryl?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18303/1876)

Answer (score 5):

I presume you're talking about the episode ["**Alone**"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3316796/?ref_=tt_ep_ep13).

If you've only watched the beginning, things *would* look a bit odd and out of place. Because **the episode in question opens with a flashback**.

Here's part of a [recap](http://www.hypable.com/2014/03/09/the-walking-dead-season-4-episode-13-recap-to-terminus/):

> The episode began with a flashback montage of **Bob on his own
>   walking through the woods** and looking defeated. **He runs into Daryl
>   and Glenn**, who give him the Rick-approved line of questioning about
>   his apocalypse life.

From another [episode summary](http://www.wetpaint.com/walking-dead/articles/2014-03-09-season-4-episode-13-recap):

> **BOB FLASHBACK**
>
> Origin story! Sort of. The start of one, anyway. Bob even gets a cool
>   song as he’s wandering slowly through the forest.
>
> [...]
>
> He hears Daryl's chopper coming down the road to the rescue. **So this
>   is right as Daryl finds him, about a week before the start of Season
>   4**. Can you imagine Daryl literally riding in to rescue you? It’s Daryl and Glenn who come by him.

Yet another [reviewer's](http://tvrecaps.ew.com/recap/the-walking-dead-recap-season-4-episode-13/) take on it:

> **The cold open kicks off with a glimpse at pre-Prison Bob Stookey**. A haunted, tortured soul with a shady past, Bob has been an enigma for
>   most of this season. Here, he's scruffier than we're used to seeing
>   him, armed with a machete and his signature canvas/leather backpack.
>
> [...]
>
> That is until **a pickup truck and motorcycle appear on the road. Glenn
>   and Daryl approach Bob**, weapons at the ready.

Following this flashback, the scene shifts back to the present with Bob, Maggie, and Sasha fighting a group of (what else) zombies.

Comment: I'm deeply impressed by the fact that you were able to answer a question that is that... Well, why mince words? When I read it my reaction was an audible WTF?!